# ng-click doesn't fire from within template

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-click

In AngularJS, can methods be called from within templates without a directive or routeProvider to bind the scope?

My specific problem is that my main controller (AppCtrl) is located on the body of my index page. On the index I use an ngView to pull in templates according to routing. Each routeProvider has its own controller except for the default template. I assumed that because of scope inheritance I could use methods defined with the AppCtrl from the template but trying to just do a simple alert or console.log doesn't register anything. I know the $scope is getting to the template because my data shows up correctly.

This seems to be a $scope issue but I'm not certain how to address it. Do I need to create a directive to explicitly bind them?

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
   <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'
  }),
  .when('/info/:id, {
    templateUrl: 'partials/info.html'
    controller: 'InfoCtrl'
  });
});
```

controllers.js

```
var controllers = {};
controllers.AppCtrl = function($scope, $location, Factory) {
  ...
  $scope.doSomething = function() {
    alert('hello');
  };
};
myApp.controller(controllers);
```

list.html

```
<a href="#" ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</a> // no response
```

Comment: try to append it on the $rootScope object

Comment: It should work.  Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/zcybQ/).

Comment: Every time. Messed with this for an hour or two and today it works. I swear, every time I cave and ask for help things just start working on their own. Well, thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to have found the root of my problem. As described, using a function did work. When I went back to address my specific problem, once again the function refused to work. Turns out it wasn't a scope problem but a binding problem. The example I gave wasn't accurate but did help me isolate the problem. I'll demonstrate:

```html
<!-- alert fires, tries to find '#' in location, binded values do not update -->
<a href="#" ng-click="addOne()">Add 1</a> 

<!-- key binding does not update -->
<a href="#" ng-click="key = key+1" ng-init="key=0">Add 1</a>

<!-- key updates -->
<a ng-click="key = key+1" ng-init="key=0">Add 1</a>
```

For whatever reason, including an href was preventing the binded value from updating. Does anyone know if there's a "preventDefault" that can be used as a workaround so that hrefs can be included for validation? It seems that this is either a bug or ng-click is only intended to be used with buttons.

Comment: 1. Look for the examples in ngHref documentation, for a preventDefault style click (down the page - 5 clicks examples demo) - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: 2. Second thing- you can always write a directive and add it to your element as an attribute, to do preventDefault

Comment: @neoswf thanks for adding the link. I don't believe this was in their docs at the time.

Comment: Yes, the same goes to the `ng-click` for button inside the `<form action="#">`. I removed the `action="#"` attribute and it works! Thanks to your answer!